# Convert two lists to a dictionary but Sum the values for Same Keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow myself but have been using the resources here for quite a while - thanks!

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c','c']
list_2 = [2,2,2,2]
```

I want to combine both the lists and get add values of the same keys

```
my_dict = dict(zip(stream_ids, times))
```

but whenever I combine the lists to dictionaries - value for the key gets replaced by the last one

```
Output: {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```

I want both 'c' to be added to get a 4
What I want to get is

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Would your both list be of same length all the time?

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way would be to use a simple for loop:

```
stream_ids = ['a','b','c','c']
times = [2,2,2,2]
my_dict = {}
for idx, count in zip(stream_ids, times):
    if idx in dict:
        my_dict[idx] += count
    else:
        my_dict[idx] = count
```

You can probably do it in one line too using a lamda function and dictionary comprehension but that won't be very readable.

Answer (score 0):

A dict will simply overwrite existing values. You have to build your dict by your own.

```
stream_ids = ['a','b','c','c']
times = [2,2,2,2]
my_dict = {}
for s, t in zip(stream_ids, times):
    my_dict[s] = my_dict.get(s, 0) + t

print(my_dict)  # {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of other answers here, with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
stream_ids = ['a','b','c','c']
times = [2,2,2,2]
dict = defaultdict(int)
for idx, count in zip(stream_ids, times):
    dict[idx] += count
```

since the default for a new integer is 0.